# Convert (part of) XML data back to tabular data or CSV/tab separated without using scripting

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, csv, xml

Is there an easy way to convert (part of) XML data back to tabular data, so comma separated values or tab separated or Excel? I sometimes get XML log files, and for clarity and comparing it more easily with other sources it would be easier to extract the data just as a flat table, for example in Excel.

I've looked at the XMLtools plug-in and other plug-ins but couldn't find any option. So for example the data is like this:

```
<ChildTaskStatus>
  <LoadSubStatus>
    <TaskStatus>RanToCompletion</TaskStatus>
    <Template>NL_CM_0_1_1</Template>
    <ItemsTotal>41219</ItemsTotal>
    <ElapsedTime>00:00:04</ElapsedTime>
  </LoadSubStatus>
  <LoadSubStatus>
    <TaskStatus>RanToCompletion</TaskStatus>
    <Template>NL_CM_18_7_1</Template>
    <ItemsTotal>168930</ItemsTotal>
    <ElapsedTime>00:00:53</ElapsedTime>
  </LoadSubStatus>
  <LoadSubStatus>
    <TaskStatus>RanToCompletion</TaskStatus>
    <Template>NL_CM_12_8_1</Template>
    <ItemsTotal>231122</ItemsTotal>
    <ElapsedTime>00:00:43</ElapsedTime>
  </LoadSubStatus>
</ChildTaskStatus>
```

And I would like to extract the data to just this (exact format doesn't matter, any csv/tab separated or tabular format will do):

| TaskStatus | Template | ItemsTotal | ElapsedTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RanToCompletion | NL_CM_0_1_1 | 41219 | 00:00:04 |
| RanToCompletion | NL_CM_18_7_1 | 168930 | 00:00:53 |
| RanToCompletion | NL_CM_12_8_1 | 231122 | 00:00:43 |

BTW, the actual file is larger obviously, and with more tree nodes.

So, is there any way to do this easily without having to write a script for each different instance, for example an option in Excel or Notepad++? I understand I would have to at least specify the XML tags for the four columns, but I mean is there a tool or app to do this?

Comment: I'm not really seeing your point of doing it in GUI. Changing the fields in a script should be as easy as changing it in some GUI options. Also, is that table formatting a mistake in Markdown or the format that you need? That's not quite CSV.

Comment: The advantage of some app or GUI is ease of access, this comes up more often and I don't want to write a new script (ok copy&paste) everytime I need something like this. And the table formatting with `|`s were just added for readability, I've updated the question description, I meant just any csv or tabular format

Comment: Which Excel version do you have? Did you tr opening the XML file in Excel directly?

Comment: Wow ok you're right, just drag & drop into Excel and it handles it pretty well, it's so obvious but tbh it somehow never occured to me to open just a random XML file in Excel. Probably because most of the time Excel doesn't even open simple csv files that well. If you want to, you can re-post it as an answer. Btw it was Excel 365 MSO (Version 2304).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is able to import XML data into a worksheet in versions 2007 - 2021 and also latest Office 365.

There are many ways to load the data. They're listed [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/import-xml-data-6eca3906-d6c9-4f0d-b911-c736da817fa4). To quote the simpliest way:

> **Open an XML data file to import its data**
>
> 1. Click **File** > **Open**.
>    If you're using Excel 2007, click **Microsoft Office Button** > **Open**.
> 2. In the **Open** dialog box, click the drive, folder, or Internet location
>    that has the file that you want to open.
> 3. Select the file and click **Open**.
> 4. If the **Import XML** dialog box appears, the file you opened refers to
>    one or more Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformation (XSLT) style
>    sheets, so you can click one of the following options:
>
> - **Open the file without applying a style sheet** - The XML data is
>   imported in a two-dimensional table with rows and columns that shows
>   XML tags as column headings, and data in rows below the column
>   headings. The first element (the root node) is used like a title and
>   is displayed in the specified cell location. The rest of the tags are
>   sorted alphabetically across the second row. In this case, Excel
>   doesn't infer a schema, and you can't use an XML Map.
> - **Open the file with the following style sheet applied (select one)** -
>   Select the style sheet that you want to apply, and then click OK. The
>   XML data is formatted according to the style sheet that you selected.
>   **Note:** The XML data is opened as read-only in Excel so that you don't
>   accidentally save your original source file in the Excel Macro-Enabled
>   Workbook file format (.xlsm). In this case, Excel doesn't infer a
>   schema, and you can't use an XML Map.
>
> 5. If the **Open XML** dialog box appears, the XML file doesn't have any XSLT style sheet references. To open the file, click one of the following options:
>
> - Click **As an XML table** to create an XML table in a new workbook.
>   The contents of the file are imported into the XML table. If the XML
>   data file doesn't refer to a schema, Excel infers the schema from the
>   XML data file.
> - Click **As a read-only workbook.**
>   The XML data is imported in a two-dimensional table with rows and
>   columns that shows XML tags as column headings, and data in rows below
>   the column headings. The first element (the root node) is used like a
>   title and is displayed in the specified cell location. The rest of the
>   tags are sorted alphabetically across the second row. In this case,
>   Excel doesn't infer a schema, and you can't use an XML Map.
>   The XML data is opened as read-only in Excel so that you don't
>   accidentally save your original source file in the Excel Macro-Enabled
>   Workbook file format (.xlsm). In this case, Excel doesn't infer a
>   schema, and you can't use an XML Map.
>
> Click **Use the XML Source task pane**.
> The schema of the XML data file is displayed in the **XML Source** task
> pane. You can then drag elements of the schema to the worksheet to map
> those elements to the worksheet.
> If the XML data file doesn't refer to a schema, Excel infers the
> schema from the XML data file.

Or just drag & drop the `.xml` file to a new worksheet.